# UML class diagram: what is target scope of an attribute compared to owner scope?

Tags: scope, attributes, uml, target

I am drawing a class diagram using UML and with visio and have come across the topic on the scope of attributes/operations. Operations have only owner scope whereas attributes have owner and target scope. What does target scope mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing.

The term scope is used in UML only with Activities (`activityScope` in `AssociationEnd` on p. 429).

Assuming that you mean visibility by saying scope, an attribute has only one visibility within the class owning it (the 4 different chars you might see in front: `+-#~`).

An association has two ends that might have roles with those visibility indicators. The roles itself correspond to attributes on the opposite side of the association.

Comment: I meant that one sees only owner scope in the properties menu of an operation, but owner and target scope in that of an attribute. What is this target scope here?

Comment: just, the UML term is visibility for +-#~ and not scope. So just be sure to speak about the same thing ...

Comment: @granier Yes, terms should be used correctly. "scope" means "the opportunity or possibility to do or deal with something" which is similar to "visibility". But I'll make a correction.

Comment: @Hugo As explained there is no such thing.

Comment: Ok, reasonable. This is why i could not google it out. Thanks.